# When DataGridView Dropdown change value

Tags: sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010

I would like to seek help from you guys about datagrid.

When i select from a value of my dropdown in my datagridview how can i load or get its data from the database and put it inside the datagrid beside it

sample when i select an item code all colunms must be filled with the data corresponding to the itemcode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is generic, here is a theoretical answer you can follow:

Use the dropdownlist's `SelectedIndexChanged` event to pass the selected value to the database. Retrieve the values from the database corresponding to this value and fill them in a `DataSet`. Use this DataSet as the GridView's datasource. You can even use the `Datareader` instead of the dataset.